# Как осуществить запись в защищённые разделы диска?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

При попытке написать что-то близкое к редактору разделов диска я столкнулся с большой проблемой: `WriteFile` не пишет дальше 2047 сектора. Что можно сделать, какие функции с какими параметрами использовать, чтобы программа могла писать в эту область диска?

---

Возможно, мне стоит использовать `DeviceIoControl` с `FSCTL_UNLOCK_VOLUME`, `FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME`, потом уже записывать что-то функцией `WriteFile`, а после этого воспользоваться той же самой функцией - `DeviceIoControl` с одним из параметров `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME`, чтобы можно было писать дальше 2047 сектора?